# How to Hide data label in Highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

how to hide data label which is marked in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: Highcharts documentation:  http://www.highcharts.com/docs | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image you want to hide the legend not the data labels so add this to the chart config:

```
legend: {
    enabled: false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting data labels as false, which will come under plotOptions

```
  dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
            }
```